# $rootScope undefined in http interceptor response method

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an interceptor that I am configuring to load an ajax spinner.

```
interface IInterceptorScope extends angular.IRootScopeService {
        loading: number;
    }

    export class Interceptor {

        public static Factory($q: angular.IQService, $rootScope : IInterceptorScope) {
            return new Interceptor($q, $rootScope);
        }


        constructor(private $q: angular.IQService, private $rootScope: IInterceptorScope) {
            this.$rootScope.loading = 0;
        }


        public response(response) {
            console.log(response);
            this.$rootScope.loading = 1;
            return response || this.$q.when(response);
        }

        public responseError(rejection) {
            console.log(rejection.status);
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
            }

            return this.$q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

`$q` is also not defined. I'm not sure why. Could anyone help out?

EDIT: This is how I am adding the interceptor inside my `config()` block, minus other parameters, it looks like this:

```
.config($httpProvider : angular.IHttpProvider) => {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push(Interceptor.Factory);
}
```

And registering the factory:

```
.factory('Interceptor', Interceptor)
```

As a reference, I was looking at the first answer here:

[AngularJS global $http state ajax loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604748/angularjs-global-http-state-ajax-loader)

`$rootScope` has the loading property here, but that is in plain JavaScript, so I'm not sure if it has to do with the way the TypeScript is here.

Comment: you are not getting the error inside responseError because probably your code does not hit that block

Comment: Please show how you register the interceptor?

Comment: Hi there, I just re-edited my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular calls the `response` method without setting `this`; to handle this with TypeScript, use a function property to capture `this` like:

```
public response = (response) => {
   console.log(response);
   this.$rootScope.loading = 1;
   return response || this.$q.when(response);
}
```

Same for `responseError` as well.

Comment: This was it. Thank you very much! May I ask if this is only applicable to http interceptor methods, or does this happen in other circumstances?

Comment: @Thomas - It's pretty common when your methods are being used as callbacks, though it's dependent on the calling code. There's a few places in Angular that you'll run into it - eg., directive link function.